# Format historical data for forecasting with calendar variables

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting, categorical-data

I have hourly time series data for the year 2015. This data corresponds to power consumption of a big commercial building. I want to use this data to predict the usage for the year 2016. To develop a forecasting model, I need to format this data in a suitable format.

I am planning to use following features to predict the 2016 usage: (1) day of week, (2) time of the day (3) temperature, (4) year 2015 usage.
I am able to create the first 3 features but the fourth one seems tricky.

How should I arrange the 2015 data so that for a particular day of 2016 I can use the corresponding day data of year 2015. My concern is :

- I should not use the weekend day data of 2015 to predict the usage of working day
- There are some days in 2015, where data is missing for entire day data. For the corresponding day in 2016, how should I account for these missing readings

Here, I have created  dummy data corresponding to the year 2015 and 2016.

```
library(xts)
set.seed(123)
seq1 <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01"),as.POSIXct("2015-12-31"), by = "hour")
data1 <- xts(rnorm(length(seq1),150,5),seq1)
seq2 <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01"),as.POSIXct("2016-09-30"), by = "hour")
data2 <- xts(rnorm(length(seq2),140,5),seq2)
```

---

Let me give an example to clarify my problem:

1. Suppose model is: `lm( output ~ dayofweek + timeofday + temperature + lastyearusage, data = xxx)`
2. Now suppose I want to predict the usage on 2 oct 2016(`dayY`), using the `lastyearusage` onm2 oct 2015(`dayX`). In this step, issue is 1) How should I ensure that`dayX` is not a weekend day if `dayY` is a working day. I am sure that in this case if I use `dayX` to predict `dayY` without keeping a check on day type output will get messy.

Comment: Since you are already using day of the week (Sun, Mon, etc.), you could include week number to approximate the date structure of 2015 to get around having to match up exact dates.

Answer (score 0):

There might be already a function in a package to do this, but post here a custom function to add all these kinds of calendar variables (including the week-end info) to a data.frame containing a date/hour column. Fake data:

```
df <- data.frame(datetime=seq(as.POSIXlt("2013/01/01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXlt("2013/12/31 23:00:00"), by="hour"), variable=rnorm(8760))
####              datetime    variable
#### 1 2013-01-01 00:00:00  1.68959052
#### 2 2013-01-01 01:00:00  0.02023722
#### 3 2013-01-01 02:00:00 -0.42080942
```

The code for the function:

```
CreateCalendarVariables = function(df, id_column=NULL) {
  df <- data.frame(df)
  if (is.null(id_column)) stop("Id column for the datetime variable is a mandatory argument")
  temp <- df[, id_column]
  if (  !(class(temp)[1] %in% c("Date", "POSIXct", "POSIXt", "POSIXlt"))  ){
    stop("the indicated datetime variable doesn't have the suitable format")
  }
  require(lubridate)
  df['year']      <- year(temp)
  df['.quarter']  <- quarter(temp)
  df['.month']       <- month(temp)
  df['.week']    <- week(temp)
  df['.DMY']        <- as.Date(temp)
  df['.dayinyear']     <- yday(temp)
  df['.dayinmonth']   <- mday(temp)
  df['.weekday']    <- wday(temp, label=T, abbr=FALSE) %>% factor(., levels=levels(.)[c(2,3,4,5,6,7,1)])
  df['.is_we']      <- df$.weekday %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")
  if(class(temp)[1] != "Date"){
    df['.hour']    <- factor(hour(temp))
  }
  return(df)
}
```

Then you just have to specify the N° of column containing the date format. If you need for your model these variables in factor format, feel free to adapt the code:

```
CreateCalendarVariables(df, 2)
#### Error in CreateCalendarVariables(df, 2) : 
####   the indicated datetime variable doesn't have the suitable format
CreateCalendarVariables(df, 1)
####              datetime    variable year .quarter .month .week       .DMY .dayinyear .dayinmonth .weekday .is_we .hour
#### 1 2013-01-01 00:00:00  1.68959052 2013        1      1     1 2012-12-31          1           1  Tuesday  FALSE     0
#### 2 2013-01-01 01:00:00  0.02023722 2013        1      1     1 2013-01-01          1           1  Tuesday  FALSE     1
```

To answer your last question, If an entire level is missing from the calibration dataset (i.e. one whole weed and you're using `.Week` as a predictor), you 'll need to impute the data first.

Comment: My question is not how to get the features from time-series data. But, how to ensure that days of 2015 line up with the days of 2016.  Another is to account for missing data of 2015 in predicting year 2016.

Comment: @HaroonRashid Hi I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. You want to include each day of the year as an explanatory variable, like "25-sept"? I'm sorry but i work with energy consumption modeling for buildings and i've never seen such practice... The variables I create with my function aren't sufficient to characterize each day of the year?

Comment: for the missing data if you ask for an algorithm to impute it depends greatly on the size of the "holes". if the holes are bigger than the high seasonality (like a whole week), you could go with a machine learning technique, if they are isolated days, you can go with `ets`. You'll find better answers in CrossValidated website

Comment: Now I have provided a simple example in the main question. See if you can get it now.

Comment: ok i don't have an explicit solution but first observation is that given 2 random years, the proportion of dates that are the same (still WE or still week) are like 50%...so 50% of your predictions will fall in this case. But if you really want to do this, you should maybe build 2 separate models, one using last year info when the dates match, the other that doesn't. My function has already this variable, and you can subset by mathing it between the years.